# File upload form validation is not working in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.1

I am using form validation to upload file in laravel 5.1,

```
  class FileUploadRequest extends Request {

   public function rules() {
    return ['file' => 'required', 'max:2048', 'mimes:pdf,png,jpeg,jpg'];
}

  public function upload(FileUploadRequest $request) {
  }
```

But it is not validating both size and mime.. what is wrong with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the rules function like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,png,jpeg,jpg|size:2048',
    ];
}
```